# https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ - Double negation introduction -

Tags: logic

How can we introduce double-negation? For example, p is the same as ~~p.

I am not able to find how to introduce ~~ in https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Is there anything like DNI, similar to DNE?

Comment: If i said 'This is not *not* a hat..', it wouldn't be the same as asserting the things straightforward hatness..

Comment: That site might not have a way to derive DNI. The [Wikipedia article on double negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation) gives a system with a derivation of DNI, but I'm not competent to translate that system into the one the linked-to site is using.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose ¬p. This contradicts p (by rule ¬E). Therefore, ¬¬p (by rule ¬I).

Comment: I followed this idea. I was curious whether there is a DNI